# Search the object value with hashtables in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash, hashtable

I have implemented a partial search in react component.

I am using following function to return the array of results.
The function works fine but my array length is in 1000s. After reading through similar questions I feel that hashtable may improve the performance I am curious to know how we implement this using the hashtables.

```
searchArray=[{name:"xyz",id:"1123"},{name:"abc",id:"2356"}]
```

```
    let filterOptions = state.searchArray
      .filter(
        material =>
          material.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) > -1
      )
      .slice(0, 4);
```

Here is where I have reached. I am confused how to proceed with the filter part

```
     const itemsByName = {};
      for (const item of searchArray) {
        itemsByName[item.name] = item;
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Note that a hashtable will only help you with a specific property, such as `name`. If you need to search on multiple properties, you generally end up with multiple hashtables (one per property). And a basic implementation will only help you with whole values (not partial matches). Supporting partial matches becomes rather more complex.

Comment: an 1000s length array on the client side?

Comment: Source of data is API